# Can't change UITableView height dynamically

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Another problem - can't change UITableView height dynamically. If I change it in xib, it doesn't reduce when it is needed. Stupid problem, but can't resolve it for a whole day.
So, when contentSize is less than initial tableView height, it must reduce tableView height. If contentSize is more than initial tableView height, it must increase tableView height.

My code is here:  https://github.com/serg1991/diplom_newbase/blob/master/diplom/BiletChildViewController.m

Comment: What are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening to your table view's height? Please clarify.

Comment: OK, when contentSize is less than initial tableView height, it must reduce tableView height. If contentSize is more than initial tableView height, it must increase tableView height.

Comment: @serg1991 I think you had a very simple mistake on your if-else code. What if commonsize value is 10? It will go through all if-else statement and finally return 200. So you need to return value immediately when getting in if else statement.

Comment: OK, fixed it. But problem remains.

Comment: @serg1991 what is your log saying? add following code to just before if-else statement: NSLog(@"Вопрос %d. Вариант %d. after = %f", (int)_index + 1, indexPath.row, commonsize);

Comment: @brianLikeApple 2014-03-19 21:55:23.352 diplom[9513:60b] Вопрос 1. Вариант 0. after = 53.685001
2014-03-19 21:55:23.353 diplom[9513:60b] Вопрос 1. Вариант 1. after = 17.895000
2014-03-19 21:55:23.354 diplom[9513:60b] Вопрос 1. Вариант 2. after = 89.475006
2014-03-19 21:55:23.356 diplom[9513:60b] Вопрос 1. Вариант 3. after = 35.790001
2014-03-19 21:55:23.368 diplom[9513:60b] Вопрос 1. Вариант 0. after = 53.685001
2014-03-19 21:55:23.369 diplom[9513:60b] Вопрос 1. Вариант 1. after = 17.895000
2014-03-19 21:55:23.370 diplom[9513:60b] Вопрос 1. Вариант 2. after = 89.475006